# Use of the verb "to cherish" to describe an active action

Tags: word-in-context

Can the verb "to cherish" be used to describe an active action in the sense of taking care of, protecting or simply remaining affectionately by someone's side as in the sentence below?

> Sleep my little princess, there is no longer any threat, no one can do you any harm anymore. I'll be by your side all night long. Sleep my little princess and I'll **cherish** you.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I checked, lots of them. Google translator, dictionary.com, vocabulary.com, merriam-webster and others too. From what I could deduce, this verb "to cherish" could only be used to express a feeling and not a concrete action as in the case of this sentence, but I was still in doubt whether this use would be possible or not, hence my question.

Comment: I'd say NO, not today. The full OED has definition #5 *To take affectionate care of (a thing); to keep or guard carefully*. ***Obsolete*** except as passing into 7. And definition #7 is *To entertain in the mind, harbour fondly, encourage, cling to (a hope, feeling, design, etc.).* Which they say is ***The most frequent current sense.*** So, to repeat, you can't really use ***cherish*** to mean ***take care of / look after*** today.

Comment: Thank you so much. What led me to ask the question is that recently I discovered a text about marriage, and then several similar ones with small variations, but in all of them I found something like: "...for richer or for poorer, to love and to cherish as long as you both may live". That's when I had doubts about the possibility of using the verb "to cherish" in this sense.

Comment: Also in the "Meanings" section of the OED there are 12 entries and among them appears: "1340-cherish, v. To treat with fostering care, foster tenderly, nurse (children, young creatures)" and in the case of my text the person would deductibly be talking to a child (my little princess), my doubt continued. Please forgive me if I was unable to express myself satisfactorily and thank you again.